# Immutablejs : Transform a List to a Map

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a List and I would like to transform it to a Map

```
const arr = [23,45,56,67];
const iArr = fromJS(arr);
```

I would like to have an Immutable like that :

```
{
  23: false,
  45: false,
  56: false
  ...
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, use `reduce` -

```js
var l = Immutable.List.of(23,45,56,67).reduce((map,value)=>map.set(value, false), Immutable.Map());
console.log(l.toJSON());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```